# maximum number validation in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, max, increment

i will try to do my best to describe my problem.

I created a Schema with Mongoose trying to put a maximum like this:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const inventorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userID: { type: String, require: true, unique: true},
    mana: { type: Number, default: 0, max: 100,min: 0},
    pickaxe: { type: Number, default: 0},
    sword: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    stone: { type: Number, default: 0},
    iron: { type: Number, default: 0},
    gold: { type: Number, default: 0},
});

const model = mongoose.model("InventoryModels", inventorySchema);

module.exports = model;
```

The second thing I wanted to do was to increment 1 every 60 seconds to my "mana" variable with this code :

```js
const manaAdd = async () => await inventoryModel.updateMany({},
    {
        $inc: {
            mana: 1
        }
    }
);
setInterval(manaAdd, 30000);
```

but there is nothing to do in any case my mana variable ended up exceeding 100...
If you can help I would be grateful to you

ZartaX0O3

Answer (score 1):

Nothing change here is the code

```js
const opts = { runValidators: true };
const manaAdd = async () => await inventoryModel.updateMany({}, { $inc: {mana: 1 }}, opts);
setInterval(manaAdd, 30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

From Mongoose document

> In the above examples, you learned about document validation. Mongoose also supports validation for update(), updateOne(), updateMany(), and findOneAndUpdate() operations. Update validators are off by default - you need to specify the runValidators option.

So you have to set runValidater to true like the follwoing code

```
const opts = { runValidators: true };
Toy.updateOne({}, { color: 'not a color' }, opts, function(err) {
  assert.equal(err.errors.color.message,
    'Invalid color');
});
```

Comment: Hi try to do this but nothing change "mana" exceed 100...